# Entered date disappears on entering next field

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datepicker, datagrid

I have DatePicker embedded in DataGrid bound to MySQL database. The issue is that when the user enters the date, then starts to enter data in the next field of DataGrid, the date disappears.

If this is a bug, then maybe there is a workaround. If there is something missing or incorrect in my code, then I hope to become enlightened.

I will paste a synopsis of the code after the Steps to the Problem. And all files for the Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Project will be temporarily available for download at https://drive.google.com/file/d/121F0FigAmmyejkn6Zimd2gZ8-5WR20jm/view?usp=sharing

Setup:

Unzip iacc_core.zip into a directory of your choosing.

Subdirectory acc_db contains MySQL schema and data. Hopefully, you can do a data import in MySQL Workbench to load test scheme with test data. The problem might have nothing to do with MySQL, so binding to something other than a MySQL database might elicit the problem, as well.

You will need to adjust directory paths and set up database connections (if you use the sample data database).

Steps:

1. Compile and Run (i.e. Press F5).
   Observe: The program opens. Focus is on the last row of the top DataGrid (Transactions).
2. Tab twice, then enter date "7/20/2020".
   Observe date "7/20/2020" showing in DataPicker.
3. Tab once to "Ref" column. Type "2".
   Observe the problem: DatePicker date disappears. The date should stay.

### Synopsis of the code

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="iacc.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:iacc"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="IACC - Transaction Journal" Height="720" Width="1000" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Closing="Window_Closing" 
                     >
    
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
        <Label Content="_Transactions" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <DataGrid Name="DataGrid_Transactions" Height="186" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      TabIndex="0" SelectionMode="Extended" 
                      MouseLeftButtonDown="DataGrid_Transactions_MouseLeftButtonDown" KeyDown="DataGrid_Transactions_KeyDown" 
                      InitializingNewItem="DataGrid_Transactions_InitializingNewItem" 
                       >
                
                <DataGrid.Columns >
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="col_uid" Binding="{Binding uid}" Visibility="Hidden" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="col_date" Header="Date" Width="100" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <DatePicker Name="dg_tr_cell_date_picker" 
                                            SelectedDate="{Binding date_trans, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                            ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
                                            TextBlock.TextAlignment="Right"     />
                                
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="col_ref"  Binding="{Binding reference}" Header="Ref" Width="80" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="col_contact" Binding="{Binding contact}" Header="Contact" Width="200"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="col_descript" Binding="{Binding description}" Header="Description" Width="300"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <DockPanel Width="260"  >
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="170" >
                                <Bold><Run Text="Del"/></Bold><Run Text=" Delete row"/><LineBreak/>
                                <Bold><Run Text="Shift+Tab"/></Bold><Run Text=" Pevious cell"/><LineBreak/>
                                <Bold><Run Text="Ctrl+Up"/></Bold><Run Text=" First row"/><LineBreak/>
                                <Bold><Run Text="Ctrl+Down"/></Bold><Run Text=" Last row"/><LineBreak/>
                                <LineBreak/>
                                <Bold><Run Text="Alt+Down" /></Bold><Run Text=" Open Date Picker" /><LineBreak />
                                    <Run Text="    (when focus on Date Picker)"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </DockPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="20,10,0,0" >
            <Label Content="Transaction _Lines" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid_Lines" Width="960" Height="150" TabIndex="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lcol_uid" Header="UID" Binding="{Binding uid}" Visibility="Hidden" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lcol_uid_transactions" Header="UID Trans"  Binding="{Binding uid_transaction}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lcol_line_num" Header="Line Num" Binding="{Binding line_num}" Visibility="Hidden" SortDirection="Ascending" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lcol_entity" Header="Entity" Binding="{Binding entity}" Width="100" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lcol_financial_stmt" Header="Fin Stmt" Binding="{Binding financial_stmt}" Width="60" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lcol_acct_group" Header="Account Group" Binding="{Binding acct_group}" Width="100" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lcol_acct_path" Header="Account Path" Binding="{Binding acct_path}" Width="300" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lcol_line_description" Header="Line Description" Binding="{Binding line_description}" Width="200" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lcol_quantity" Header="Qty" Binding="{Binding quantity}" Width="50" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lcol_multiplier" Header="Mult" Binding="{Binding multiplier}" Width="50" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lcol_amount" Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding amount}" Width="100"  />
                </DataGrid.Columns>

            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0"  >
            <Label Content="Row" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBox x:Name="TextBox_trans_row" Width="50" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,0,0,0" TabIndex="2"  />
            <Label Content="ID" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
            <TextBox x:Name="TextBox_trans_id" Width="50" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,0,0,0" TabIndex="3"  />
            <Button x:Name="Button_update_transaction_lines" Content="_Update Transaction Lines" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,0,0,0"
                    Click="Button_update_transaction_lines_Click" />
            <TextBox x:Name="TextBox_DragDrop_Events" Width="200" Height="250" Margin="20,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Automation.Peers;
using System.Windows.Automation.Provider;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySqlX.XDevAPI.Relational;

using iacc_core;



namespace iacc
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly string conn_str = "server=chevron;user id=admin;password=admin;database=indinfer_accounting;allowuservariables=True;persistsecurityinfo=True";
        private MySql_F data_transactions = null;
        private bool FirstKeyOrClick = false;

        private MySql_F data_lines = null;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string sel_str = "SELECT uid, date_trans, reference, contact, description FROM transactions ORDER BY uid";
            data_transactions = MySql_F.DataGrid_CRUD_DataSource(DataGrid_Transactions, conn_str, sel_str);

            DataGrid_Transactions.Focus();
            DataGrid_Transactions.ScrollIntoView(DataGrid_Transactions.Items[Last_Index(DataGrid_Transactions.Items.Count)]);
            DataGrid_Transactions.SelectedIndex = Last_Index(DataGrid_Transactions.Items.Count);

            // Now get the detail grid working. Get the id from the *** DataTable *** that is the source for DataGrid_Transactions
        }

        private int Last_Index(int count)
        {
            return ((count <= 1) ? 0 : count - 1);
        }



        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            data_transactions.Update_Database();
        }

  
        private bool init_datagrid_transactions()
        {
            if (FirstKeyOrClick)
            {
                return false;
            }

            FirstKeyOrClick = true;

            // Give DataGrid_Transactions keyboard focus on the last row
            DataGrid_Transactions.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Last));

            // Cause DataGrid_Transactions to accept input on key press instead of transferring focus to next control
            Keyboard_F.SendKey(Key.Home);
            Keyboard_F.SendKey(Key.Home);

            return true;
        }

        private void DataGrid_Transactions_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (init_datagrid_transactions())
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }


        private void DataGrid_Transactions_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (init_datagrid_transactions())
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }


        private void Button_update_transaction_lines_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            /*
             * Get item index from DataGrid_Transactions. Use index to get ID from the bound DataTable.
             * Use function from Adapter to update DataGrid_Lines. The ID is a parameter for this.
             */

            int idx = DataGrid_Transactions.SelectedIndex;
            TextBox_trans_row.Text = idx.ToString();
            if (idx <= DataGrid_Transactions.Items.Count)
            {
                DataRow dr = data_transactions.data_table.Rows[idx];
                TextBox_trans_id.Text = dr.Field<int>("uid").ToString();

                string select_sql = 
                    "SELECT uid, uid_transaction, line_num, entity, financial_stmt, " +
                        "acct_group, acct_path, line_description, quantity, multiplier, amount " +
                    "FROM transaction_lines " +
                    "WHERE(uid_transaction = " + idx.ToString() + ") " +
                    "ORDER BY line_num";

                string insert_sql = 
                    "INSERT INTO transaction_lines " +
                        "(uid_transaction, line_num, entity, financial_stmt, acct_group, " +
                        "acct_path, line_description, quantity, multiplier, amount) " +
                    "VALUES(@uid_transaction, @line_num, @entity, @financial_stmt, @acct_group, " +
                        "@acct_path, @line_description, @quantity, @multiplier, @amount)";

                string update_sql = "UPDATE transaction_lines " +
                    "SET uid_transaction = @uid_transaction, " +
                        "line_num = @line_num, " +
                        "entity = @entity, " +
                        "financial_stmt = @financial_stmt, " +
                        "acct_group = @acct_group, " +
                        "acct_path = @acct_path, " +
                        "line_description = @line_description, " +
                        "quantity = @quantity, " +
                        "multiplier = @multiplier, " +
                        "amount = @amount " +
                    "WHERE(transaction_lines.uid = @uid)";

                string delete_sql =
                    "DELETE FROM transaction_lines " +
                    "WHERE(transaction_lines.uid = @uid)";

                data_lines = MySql_F.DataGrid_CRUD_DataSource(DataGrid_Lines, conn_str, 
                    select_sql, insert_sql, update_sql, delete_sql);
            }
        }

        private void DataGrid_Transactions_InitializingNewItem(object sender, InitializingNewItemEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dg_tr_cell_date_picker_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: If this question was already posted with a good answer, I would appreciate help finding the post.

Comment: Thank you, John. We will see if I understand when I encounter my next problem. Thank you for taking care of it by editing my title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a mistake to put the `DatePicker` in the `CellTemplate`. Input fields should be put in the `CellEditingTemplate` for the edited value to be persisted as expected. The `CellTemplate` should just display the current value, for example using a `TextBlock`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="col_date" Header="Date" Width="100" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
        <DataTemplate >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding date_trans, StringFormat=MM/dd/yyyy}" TextAlignment="Right" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DatePicker Name="dg_tr_cell_date_picker" 
                        SelectedDate="{Binding date_trans, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                           ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
                        TextBlock.TextAlignment="Right" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This is how the other types of columns work.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. A relatively minor change to my code makes it work decently, without DatePicker losing data.

Answer (score 1):

I thank @mm8 for a good answer. The answer helped develop an alternative. This alternative allows the DatePicker button to appear at all times. It seems a matter of style preference since you don't save clicks or keystrokes with this alternative.

From the same section of code that @mm8 posted, substitute this:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="col_date" Header="Date" Width="100" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker Name="dg_tr_cell_date_picker" 
                            SelectedDate="{Binding date_trans, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                            ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
                            TextBlock.TextAlignment="Right"  
                            IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="False"       />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker Name="dg_tr_cell_date_picker" 
                            SelectedDate="{Binding date_trans, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                            ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
                            TextBlock.TextAlignment="Right" 
                            Background="Green"    />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Note that in the first DatePicker (CellTemplate), I needed to add

```
IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="False"
```

I think IsHitTestVisible and Focusable prevent editing in Normal Mode. I would upvote someone's explanation of why. This seems to be the thing that keeps DataPicker from losing data even though it appears twice for the same column.

I added

```
Background="Green"
```

to the Editable version to make transitions between edit and normal modes apparent. The color of the background is not what makes this solution work.